# Why is 301 returned in Spring cloud netflix zuul SimpleHostRoutingFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am working on version 2.2.6.RELEASE upgrade from spring boot 1.4.1.RELEASE
I am using spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.2.RELEASE in my project and returning a different HTTP code for the same route path at SimpleHostRoutingFilter.class while changing to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.2.RELEASE

- spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.2.RELEASE: 200
- spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.2.RELEASE: 301

```
  zuul:
    routes:
      pages:
        path: /pages/**
        url: https://pages.oss.blahblah.com
        sensitive-headers: >
          host
```

I can't understand why this is happening.
Why is 301 returned in spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.2.RELEASE?

- request header

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
host = zvzv.service.com:8080
connection = keep-alive
accept = */*
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with = XMLHttpRequest
referer = http://zvzv.service.com:8080/
accept-encoding = gzip, deflate
accept-language = ko,ko-KR;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie = language=ko_KR; LC=ko_KR; timezone=Asia/Seoul; TZ=Asia/Seoul;
```

- response header

```
HTTP/1.1 301
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 04:32:31 GMT
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://oss.blahblah.com:8080/service/inplace/ko_KR/how-to-use-platform.md?_=1592970280744
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; connect-src 'self' uploads.oss.blahblah.com media.oss.blahblah.com www.githubstatus.com oss.blahblah.com; font-src assets.oss.blahblah.com; form-action 'self' oss.blahblah.com gist.oss.blahblah.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; frame-src render.oss.blahblah.com; img-src * data:; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; script-src assets.oss.blahblah.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' assets.oss.blahblah.com
X-Runtime-rack: 0.002241
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Because the proxied service returns a 301

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for comment. why is it working normally in spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.2.RELEASE?

Comment: @spencergibb It was Host header issue. thanks